# Gromov-Hausdorff distances between isometric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry, hausdorff-distance, gromov-hausdorff-limit

Well I know that the Gromov-Hausdorff distance between isometric spaces is 0. But I don't know how can I prove it.
Well, if I use the following definition of Gromov-Hausdorff distance:

> If X,Y are metric spaces, the $d_{GH}(X,Y)$ is the infimum value of $r > 0$ where exists a metric space $Z$ with $X',Y' \subset Z$ and isometric to $X$ and $Y$ respectively and $d_H(X',Y') < r$.

Well, if I use the definition I have that $X$ and $Y$ are isometric so $X'$ and $Y'$ are also isometric. So now I have to prove that $d_H(X',Y') = 0$ but I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $Z=X$, $X'=X$, and $Y'=X$. Then $d_H(X',Y')=0$.

Comment: But this case is a particular case, it isn't a prove for it no?

Comment: I just showed that for all $r>0$ there are spaces as in the definition you cite. So, their infimum, i.e., the GH distance, is $0$.

Comment: Not only is that a proof, but that's the proper way to prove it. The proof requires you to show *there exists* a metric space $Z$ with some properties. The proper way to prove that $Z$ exists is to construct it, i.e. you construct a particular $Z$ and verify that it satisfies the required properties.